# Instruments: Target failed to run: already running on exited process

Tags: instruments

I quit out of Instruments, the iPhone simulator, Xcode, and unplugged and reconnected my iPhone. I still get the following error.

[image: Instruments Screenshot]

This first answer below didn't help.

Comment: I've got just the same problem (both in Instruments GUI and from console). It appears, that the only solutions are restarting the device or waiting for some time. It would be great, of course, if someone could explain, what is this 'Exited process' process...

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch off your iPhone and restart it. Sometimes this is the only way to fix a problem with some process being hanged in the debugger, maybe it also works for Instruments.